# How to skip null & empty when importing AD contacts?

Tags: powershell

My script to import AD contacts to a new domain fails because some values are Null & Empty. I exported the contacts as an XML. How do I fix this with an IF statement to create the AD Object and skip if Null & Empty, but fill it in if there is a value?

**Import Script**

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$import = Import-Clixml "C:\Users\Downloads\contacts.xml"
foreach($contact in $import){
    $newContact=@{
        path      = "OU=Test,OU=domain,OU=B"
        type      = "Contact"
        Name      = $contact.name
        otherAttributes = @{
            givenname = $contact.givenName
            sn = $contact.sn
            mail = $contact.mail
            displayName = $contact.displayName
            cn = $contact.cn
            co = $contact.co
            company = $contact.company
            l = $contact.l
            mailNickname = $contact.mailNickname
            telephoneNumber = $contact.telephoneNumber
            st = $contact.st
            streetAddress = $contact.streetAddress
            postalcode = $contact.postalcode
            physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $contact.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
            mobile = $contact.mobile
        }
    }
    New-ADObject @newContact
}
```

**Error**

```
New-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'OtherAttributes'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
At C:\Users\Documents\Scripts\contacts-import.ps1:26 char:18
+     New-ADObject @newContact
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADObject
 
New-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'OtherAttributes'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
At C:\Users\Documents\Scripts\contacts-import.ps1:26 char:18
+     New-ADObject @newContact
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirecto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the `OtherAttributes` dictionary one entry at a time, and test if a corresponding value actually exists:

```
# ...
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$import = Import-Clixml "C:\Users\Downloads\contacts.xml"
$potentialAttributes = @(
    'givenName'
    'sn'
    'mail'
    'displayName'
    'cn'
    'co'
    'company'
    'l'
    'mailNickname'
    'telephoneNumber'
    'st'
    'streetAddress'
    'postalcode'
    'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'
    'mobile'
)

foreach($contact in $import){
    $newContact=@{
        path      = "OU=Test,OU=domain,OU=B"
        type      = "Contact"
        Name      = $contact.name
        OtherAttributes = @{}
    }

    foreach($attributeName in $potentialAttributes){
        if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($contact.$attributeName)){
            $newContact['OtherAttributes'][$attributeName] = $contact.$attributeName
        }
    }
    
    New-ADObject @newContact
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Can you help explain this to me? I get the concept, but the coding is foreign.

 if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($contact.$attributeName)){
            $newContact['OtherAttributes'][$attributeName] = $contact.$attributeName

Comment: @a3kop Which part looks foreign? `$contact.$attributeName` is that same as `$contact.givenName` if `$attributeName = 'givenName'`. `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty` returns `$true` if the value provided is either null or an empty string. `$newContact['OtherAttributes'][$attributeName]` is just a nested hashtable/dictionary access operation.

Comment: `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty returns $true if the value provided is either null or an empty string.` This part. Thanks for the explanation!